# Div Following Cursor With Dead Zone

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an element follow the cursor with an added dead zone behaviour.

As long as the cursor moves within a radius of 100 pixels around the element, then the element should not move. Otherwise the element should follow behind the cursor when the 100 pixel radius is exceeded (in any direction). I don't want the orb to catch up with the cursor so it would prevent clicking on other elements, but rather stay on the edge of the dead zone.

In my example, the element is pushed away from the cursor, which is not what I want.

NOTE: I want a native JavaScript solution that doesn't use a library, like jQuery's stop().animate().

```js
const $TheOrb = document.getElementById('TheOrb')

const deadzone = 100

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event = {}) => {
    const x = Math.abs(event.pageX - ($TheOrb.getBoundingClientRect().left + $TheOrb.clientWidth / 2))
    const y = Math.abs(event.pageY - ($TheOrb.getBoundingClientRect().top + $TheOrb.clientHeight / 2))

    if (x > deadzone || y > deadzone)
        $TheOrb.style.transform = `translate(${
            event.pageX - $TheOrb.clientWidth / 2 + deadzone // Don't work correctly with dead zone!
        }px, ${
            event.pageY - $TheOrb.clientHeight / 2 + deadzone // Don't work correctly with dead zone!
        }px)`
})
```

```css
#TheOrb {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-style: open-sans;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="TheOrb">Voff!</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but just so I understand - you want the div to not move unless the mouse moves within the 100 pixel limit?

Comment: @Nicholas Smith Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Version

I have made a new version, which uses `transform: translate()` instead of the `left` and `right` properties. It also ensures the orb stops at the `deadzone` distance when moving towards the cursor. *I have also removed `transition: 0.2s`*.

```js
const $TheOrb = document.getElementById('TheOrb');

const deadzone = 100;

let orbX = 0;
let orbY = 0;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const x = e.pageX - (orbX + $TheOrb.clientWidth / 2);
  const y = e.pageY - (orbY + $TheOrb.clientHeight / 2);

  if (x > deadzone) {
    orbX = e.pageX - $TheOrb.clientWidth / 2 - deadzone;
  } else if (Math.abs(x) > deadzone) {
    orbX = e.pageX - $TheOrb.clientWidth / 2 + deadzone;
  }

  if (y > deadzone) {
    orbY = e.pageY - $TheOrb.clientHeight / 2 - deadzone;
  } else if (Math.abs(y) > deadzone) {
    orbY = e.pageY - $TheOrb.clientHeight / 2 + deadzone;
  }

  $TheOrb.style.transform = `translate(${orbX}px, ${orbY}px)`;
});
```

```css
#TheOrb {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-style: open-sans;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="TheOrb">Voff!</div>
```

## Old Version

I have rewritten the JavaScript to use the CSS `left` and `top` properties instead of `transform`. I have also added `transition: 0.2s;` to the CSS, so that the orb follows the mouse smoothly.

```js
const $TheOrb = document.getElementById('TheOrb');

const deadzone = 100;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const x = Math.abs(e.pageX - (Number($TheOrb.style.left.replace('px', '')) + $TheOrb.clientWidth / 2));
  const y = Math.abs(e.pageY - (Number($TheOrb.style.top.replace('px', '')) + $TheOrb.clientHeight / 2));

  if (x > deadzone || y > deadzone) {
    $TheOrb.style.left = e.pageX - $TheOrb.clientWidth / 2 + 'px';
    $TheOrb.style.top = e.pageY - $TheOrb.clientHeight / 2 + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
#TheOrb {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-style: open-sans;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="TheOrb">Voff!</div>
```

Comment: Through this source: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/ it's stated that translate gives smoother animations, like so: $TheOrb.style.transform = `translate(${ event.pageX - $TheOrb.clientWidth / 2 }px, ${ event.pageY - $TheOrb.clientHeight / 2 }px). Do you know how your example can be updated to use translate and how to stop the orb at the edge of the dead zone as was my question? I did not understand what Number and replace does.

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to edit it today, but I'll have a look at it tomorrow. Also, `replace()` is used to get rid of the *px* on the end of the string and `Number()` converts it to a number.

Comment: OUT! =) The idea is to have an element following along for convenience. So I don't want the orb to prevent any clicks the user might do. But I want the orb to follow at a specified distance (the dead zone), and not catch up with the cursor. Would be perfect if the orb stayed the dead zone distance so you can go back to it without it moving.

Comment: Seems like a fun idea, but it could cause more problems than it solves. If you ever need an alternative, you could always just use a fixed div .

Comment: It would be too easy! ;) Thank you and it be greatly appreciated if you have some time tomorrow to take a look at it.

Comment: I realised you were converting the original position of the element with Number() and replace(). Wouldn't $TheOrb.getBoundingClientRect().top and $TheOrb.getBoundingClientRect().left be more appropriate?

Comment: Not in the code I made, as it would keep referring to the original position. Maybe it will work with `transform: translate()`, I'm working on it now.

Comment: I updated the code, but TheOrb is not stopping at the edge of the dead zone correctly if you have time to take a look.

Comment: Daemon Beast Amazing job! I hope this also will benefit any other person who wants something similar. Please tell me if I can promote your solution any further. Thank you.

Comment: @DarkCodeWiz No need to promote anything, it's here in case anyone needs it .